# $\sin\left(\frac 1x\right)$ is not uniformly continuous in $(0,1)$ - is my proof correct?

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, uniform-continuity

Scratchwork:

$$\forall x,y\in(0,1),\,x+y\gt x\sqrt{1-y^2}+y\sqrt{1-x^2}\implies\arcsin(x+y)\gt\arcsin(x)+\arcsin(y)$$

When $-1\le x+y\le1$. Wlog let $y\gt x$. Then:

$$\arcsin(|\sin(1/x)-\sin(1/y)|)=\arcsin(\sin(1/x)-\sin(1/y))\gt\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y}=\frac{y-x}{xy}\gt\frac{y-x}{y^2}$$

If we let this be greater than $\arcsin(\varepsilon)>0$, we have that $\frac{y-x}{\arcsin(\varepsilon)}\gt y^2$. This gives $y=\sqrt{\frac{y-x}{\arcsin\varepsilon}}\lt\sqrt{\frac{\delta}{\arcsin\varepsilon}}$ when $y-x\lt\delta$. To disprove uniform continuity, it is sufficient to show that for some $\varepsilon\gt0$ we have $\forall\delta\gt0,\,\exists y,x:|y-x|\lt\delta$ but $|f(x)-f(y)|\gt\varepsilon$. If this can be shown for $\delta\in(0,a)$, then it holds for $\delta\in(0,b)$ for all $b\gt a$ as well, so considering the narrowed range of $\delta\in(0,\arcsin(\varepsilon))$ is sufficient.

Proof:

Let $1\gt\varepsilon\gt0$ and then let $\delta\in(0,\arcsin(\varepsilon))\neq\emptyset$. Let $y\in(0,\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\delta}{\arcsin\varepsilon}})\subset(0,1)$ and let $x\in(y-\delta,y-\frac{\delta}{4})\neq\emptyset$, such that $-1\le\sin(1/x)-\sin(1/y)\le1$. Then $1\gt\delta\gt y-x\gt\frac{\delta}{4}\gt0$ and $\arcsin$ is well defined for $y-x$, and importantly $|y-x|\lt\delta$.

$$y\lt\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\delta}{\arcsin\varepsilon}}\implies y^2\lt\frac{1}{4}\frac{\delta}{\arcsin\varepsilon}\implies\arcsin\varepsilon\lt\frac{\delta}{4y^2}\lt\frac{y-x}{y^2}\lt\frac{y-x}{xy}=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y}$$

By the increasing property of sine in $(0,1)$ and what was said during the scratchwork:

$$\varepsilon\lt\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y}\right)\lt\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)-\sin\left(\frac{1}{y}\right)$$

Despite $|y-x|\lt\delta$ for all $\delta\gt0$. As $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary, this concludes the proof that $\sin(1/x)$ is not uniformly continuous in $(0,1)$.

Is this correct? Is there a much neater approach?

Comment: Neater approach: uniformly continuous functions preserve Cauchy sequences, and $\frac{2}{(2n+1)\pi}$ does not map to a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: @TheoBendit That seems very powerful and certainly far neater for the majority of cases - does this theorem have a name? I might try to prove this as an exercise

Comment: Not that I'm aware @FShrike. Proving it is a good idea, as it is a nice exercise for real analysis students.

Comment: Your inequality $\arcsin(|\sin(1/x)-\sin(1/y)|) > \frac{y-x}{y^2}$ does not seem reasonable -- for example, what if you take $x := \frac{1}{10\pi}$, $y := \frac{1}{9\pi}$?

Comment: @DanielSchepler Where is the fault in my logic then? I don't see how that counterexample slipped through the cracks

Comment: For what it's worth, given that I don't know anything about Cauchy sequences, I first left a hand-waving argument that involved focusing on the fact that $\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx} [\sin(1/x)]$ contains a $\frac{-1}{x^2}$ factor.  Then, I thought better of my comment, imagining that it is plausibly not that simple.  So, I deleted my comment.

Comment: @user2661923  yes it’s not rigorous (at least not immediately so) but it is certainly a good way to detect a lack of uniform continuity since $1/x^2$ is known not to be uniformly continuous on $(0,1)$. I wonder if there is some theorem: “if a function is not UC on a certain interval then neither is its antiderivative”

Comment: @user2661923 It is indeed not that simple. Uniformly continuous functions can have unbounded derivatives. The usual counterexample is $\sqrt{x}$, on $(0, 1)$ if you like. The derivative is unbounded, but the function is uniformly continuous. To see this, assume $x, y \ge 0$, and recall$$\sqrt{xy} \ge \min\{x, y\} = \frac{x + y - |x - y|}{2}.$$Rearranging this gives $x - 2\sqrt{xy} + y \le |x - y|$, so taking square roots, $|\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y}| \le \sqrt{|x - y|}$. This inequality proves uniform continuity on $[0, \infty)$, including $(0, 1)$. You might be thinking of Lipschitz continuity.

Comment: @TheoBendit Thank you for clearing that up!

Answer (score -1):

It's a bit laborious $-$ you don't need all that scratchwork and all those arcsins. I would say:

Let $\epsilon=1$. Then every pair of the form $(x_n,y_n)=\left(\frac{1}{(2n+\frac12)\pi},\frac{1}{(2n-\frac12)\pi}\right)$ satisfies $|f(x_n)-f(y_n)|=2>\epsilon$. But for any $\delta>0$, we can choose $n$ large enough so that $|x_n-y_n|<\delta$.

Comment: For the sake of my sanity (I spent a while on this question, have never proved something is *not* uniformly continuous before) is what I wrote correct, even if very verbose?

Comment: Sorry @FShrike, I'm not going to go through all that.